# Button is not working in Combobox menu

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a combobox menu. It is work without button. I add a button but it is not working. I want to run when the button is clicked. And I have no idea about JavaScript. Can someone help me? Thanks.

asd.php

```
$hello = $_POST['List3'];
echo $hello;
```

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/*
Triple Combo Script Credit
By Philip M: http://www.codingforums.com/member.php?u=186
Visit http://javascriptkit.com for this and over 400+ other scripts
*/

var categories = [];
categories["startList"] = ["Wearing Apparel","Books"]
categories["Wearing Apparel"] = ["Men","Women","Children"];
categories["Books"] = ["Biography","Fiction","Nonfiction"];
categories["Men"] = ["Shirts","Ties","Belts","Hats"];
categories["Women"] = ["Blouses","Skirts","Scarves", "Hats"];
categories["Children"] = ["Shorts", "Socks", "Coats", "Nightwear"];
categories["Biography"] = ["Contemporay","Historical","Other"];
categories["Fiction"] = ["Science Fiction","Romance", "Thrillers", "Crime"];
categories["Nonfiction"] = ["How-To","Travel","Cookbooks", "Old Churches"];

var nLists = 3; // number of select lists in the set

function fillSelect(currCat,currList){
var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));
for (i=step; i<nLists+1; i++) {
document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].length = 1;
document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;
}
var nCat = categories[currCat];
for (each in nCat) {
var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[each]); 
nOption.setAttribute('value',nCat[each]); 
nOption.appendChild(nData); 
currList.appendChild(nOption); 
} 
}

function getValue() {
    document.forms["tripleplay"].submit();
}

function init() {
fillSelect('startList',document.forms['tripleplay']['List1'])
}

navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);    

</script> 









<form name="tripleplay" action="asd.php" method="POST">
<select name='List1' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List2'])">
<option selected>Make a selection</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List2' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List3'])">
<option selected>Make a selection</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List3' onchange="getValue(this.value, this.form['List2'].value, 
this.form['List1'].value)">
<option selected >Make a selection</option>
</select>

      <center><a type="button" href="javascript: getValue()" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">GÖNDER</a></center>


</form>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're submitting this with Javascript and not just a `<button type="submit">GÖNDER</button>`? It seems all your `getValue()` does is submit the form?

Comment: I added `<button type="submit">GÖNDER</button>` and I deleted `function getValue()` Great! It's working. Thanks.

Comment: Great stuff, for reference assuming you're using Bootstrap or something similar you can still put your `class="btn btn-warning btn-lg"` styles on the `<button`>.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding a href with the javascript use "onclick", add the following:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" onclick="getValue()">GONDER</a>
```